# Jenkins: After build cancel , handle SIGTERM interruption inside the Python script in order to cleanup before finishing

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins

My Jenkins server (version 2.167) is running a shell build job that executes a script written with Python 3.7.0.

Sometimes users need to cancel the build manually (by clicking on the red button with white cross from Jenkins GUI), and the Python scripts needs to handle the interruption in order to perform cleanup tasks before exiting. Some times, the interruption is handled correctly, but others, it seems that the parent process gets terminated before the Python script can run the cleanup procedure.

At the beginning of the Python script, I defined the following:

```
def cleanup_after_int(signum, frame):
    # some cleanup code here
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, cleanup_after_int)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, cleanup_after_int)

# the rest of the script here
```

Is the code I'm using sufficient, or should I consider something more?

The Jenkins doc for aborting a build is https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Aborting+a+build

Found a pretty good document showing how this work: https://gist.github.com/datagrok/dfe9604cb907523f4a2f

Comment: My current solution is using a Post Build Task , looking for log text 'Aborted by' and executing a cleanup script.

Comment: The document https://gist.github.com/datagrok/dfe9604cb907523f4a2f is an excellent source and it helps to figure out how to handle the signals in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You describe a race:

> it seems that the parent process [sometimes] gets terminated before the Python script can run the cleanup procedure.

It would be helpful to know how you know that, in terms of the symptoms you observe.

In any event, the python code you posted looks fine. It should work as expected *if* SIGTERM is delivered to your python process. Perhaps jenkins is just terminating the parent bash. Or perhaps both bash & python are in the same process group and jenkins signals the process group. Pay attention to PGRP in `ps -j` output.

Perhaps your cleanup code is complex and requires resources that are not always available. For example, perhaps `stdout` is a pipe to the parent, and cleanup code logs to that open file descriptor, though sometimes a dead parent has closed it.

You might consider having the cleanup code first "daemonize", using this chapter 3 call: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html. Then your cleanup would at least be less racy, leading to more reproducible results when you test it and when you use it in production.

You could choose to have the parent bash script orchestrate the cleanup:

```
trap "python cleanup.py" SIGINT SIGTERM
python doit.py
```

You could choose to not worry about cleaning upon exit at all. Instead, log whatever you've dirtied, and (synchronously) clean that just before starting, then begin your regularly scheduled script that does the real work. Suppose you create three temp files, and wish to tidy them up. Append each of their names to `/tmp/temp_files.txt` just before creating each one. Be sure to flush buffers and persist the write with `fsync()` or `close()`.

Rather than logging, you could choose to clean at startup without a log. For example:

```
$ rm -f /tmp/{1,2,3}.txt
```

might suffice. If only the first two were created last time, and the third does not exist, no big deal. Use wildcards where appropriate.